# Creating Parse.Object new parse server

Tags: javascript, ios, node.js, parse-server

I am using the new open source parse server and this is what I have in the `main.js` for creating a object.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("purchaseItem", function(request, response) {
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
  var order, custom;

  Parse.Promise.as().then(function() {

    var fullreceipt;
    var receiptData = new Array();
    receiptData = request.params.receipt.titles;

    if(receiptData){
      console.log('value of recept data is good');
    }

    if (!receiptData){
      console.log('Value of receiptData is empty');
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < receiptData.length; i++) {
      console.log(receiptData[i]);
      fullreceipt = receiptData[i];  
      console.log(fullreceipt);
      //Do something
    }

    var currentUser = Parse.User.current();
    order = new Parse.Object('Order');                                
    order.set('name', request.params.name);
    order.set('email', request.params.email);
    order.set('address', request.params.address);
    order.set('zip', request.params.zip);
    order.set('city_state', request.params.city_state);
    order.set('fulfilled', false);
    order.set('charged', false); // set to false until we actually charge the card
    order.set('user', currentUser);
    order.set('receipt', request.params.receipt);
    order.set('tipAmount', request.params.tipAmount);
    order.set('taxAmount', request.params.taxAmount);
    order.set('orderInstructions', request.params.instructions);
    order.set('pickupOrDelivery', request.params.pickupOrDelivery);
    order.set('totalBillAmount', request.params.totalBill);

    return order.save().then(null, function(error) {
      console.log('Creating order object failed. Error: ' + error);
      return Parse.Promise.error('An error has occurred. Your credit card was not charged.' + order);
    });
  }
}
```

In the logs I get `value of recept data is good` but creating the object fails and I get the error message, `Creating order object failed. Error: [object Object]`
. If any one cloud help that would be great!

Comment: You can try with throw the error in the `order.save()` instead to convert it to a string.

Comment: To see the error: `JSON.stringify(error)`

Comment: Thank you so much @llya !!! All that was going wrong was I need to point the api to the new server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looks like found my own answer in a error message. What was going wrong was I need to point it to the new parse server on AWS api and not the old parse api.